# How do I find which entries are not present in a given IN clause?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I'm using this query to find the delivery location for a bunch of orders:

```
SELECT
orders_id,
orders_location
FROM orders
WHERE orders_id IN (1234, 1235, 1239, 1242)
```

Is there a way to restructure my query so that if for example order ID 1242 is not found, I get a NULL row instead of silently ignoring it? I'm using MySQL 8

Answer (score 0):

If use a `left join`:

```
select orders_id, o.orders_location
from (select 1234 as orders_id union all select 1235 union all . . .
     ) i left join
     orders o
     using (orders_id)
```